# remove /n/r in tinyMCE

Tags: r, tinymce

I have a scenario where I have to read the pagesource of the html page and save it as a string. I have to retreive this page source in tinyMCE. When i setcontent of tinyMCE to this string i get \r \n. I want them to appear as line breaks not as string. I tried replacing the strings with  but it didn't help. Please if anyone could help

```
tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode: "specific_textareas",
    theme: "advanced",
    width: "100%",
    plugins: "pagebreak,paste,fullscreen,visualchars",
    entity_encoding: "raw",
    remove_linebreaks: false,
    init_instance_callback: "customTinyMceInit",
    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1: "code,|,bold,italic,underline,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,|,fullscreen,|,bullist,numlist,|,pasteword",
    theme_advanced_buttons2: "",
    theme_advanced_buttons3: "",
    theme_advanced_buttons4: "",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
    valid_elements: "i,sub,sup",
    invalid_elements: "p, script",
    editor_deselector: "mceOthers"

});

function customTinyMceInit(inst) {
    if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {
        var parent = $(window.opener.document).contents();
        var Id = queryString["Id"];
        var Result = [];


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Modules/Management/OnlineTemplateCreation.aspx/GetTemplateByContentId",
            data: "{'Id':"+Id+"}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                Result.push(data.d);
                alert(Result[0]);
                tinyMCE.getInstanceById("RichTextBox").setContent(Result[0]);
            }



        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to replace '\r \n' characters with '< br >' in your response data.

```
function replaceLineBreaks(data) {
     var replacedData = data.replace("\r \n", "<br>");
     return replacedData;
}
```

Then try this:

```
tinyMCE.getInstanceById("RichTextBox").setContent(replaceLineBreaks(Result[0]));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

apply source formatting in init

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        apply_source_formatting : true
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for tinymce@4.3.13

```
    tinyMCE.init({
    forced_root_block: false,
    });
```

SOURCE: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#forced_root_block